# Node.js: REST client returns the value before it's returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous

I am trying to use the [node-rest-client](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client) REST client in Node.js.

When I use the following code, it returns `null` but the console prints the response after that. How can I make synchronized calls using the REST client?

```
var postRequest = function(url, args) {
  var client = new Client();
  var responseData = {};

  client.post(url, args, function(data, response) {
    responseData = data;
    console.log(responseData);
  });

  return responseData;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module internally uses Node.js' native HTTP methods, so they aren't synchronous. You can't turn an asynchronous function into a synchronous one, so you need to use a callback:

```
var postRequest = function(url, args, callback) {
  var client = new Client();
  var responseData = {};
  client.post(url, args, function(data, response) {
    responseData = data;
    callback(responseData);
  });
};
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
postRequest(url, args, function(response) {
  // response
});
```