# Updating outside variables inside a javascript function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I am developing a NodeJS application and encountered following problem:

I am using node module `node-rest-client` to issue REST requests using an API. I use `post` method provided by the module for my purpose. I need to fetch the json response and write it to seperate variables and return them.

I have defined `returnData` variable outside the `client.post` method. I need to update this `returnData` variable inside the function which is passed as a parameter to the `client.post` method.

But I have a scope issue here. Although I try to update the `returnData` variable inside that function, when execution returns from `client.post` function, I see that the same values I have set (in this case null, but may be any value) before calling `client.post` function still persists in the variable.

How can I define scope well so that I can update an outside variable inside the function which I pass as a parameter to another function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Following is my Code:

```
module.exports = function(){
    require("../config");
    var restClient = require('node-rest-client').Client;
    var client = new restClient();
    var sessionID = null,
        reqID = 1;

    var login = function(username, password){
        var requestParams = {};
        var apiParams = {};

        requestParams.jsonrpc = "2.0";
        requestParams.method = ZABBIX_API_METHODS.login;
        apiParams.user = username;
        apiParams.password = password;
        requestParams.params = apiParams;
        requestParams.id = reqID;
        requestParams.auth = null;

        var args = {
            data: requestParams,
            headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json-rpc"}    // ask response type to be application/json-rpc
        };

        var returnData = {};
        returnData.status = null;
        returnData.data = null

        client.post(ZABBIX_API, args, function(resData,rawRes){

            if(rawRes.statusCode == 200){
                returnData.status = rawRes.statusCode;
                returnData.data = resData;
            }
            else{
                returnData.status = rawRes.statusCode;
                returnData.data = "Request Failed!";
            }

            reqID = reqID + 1;
            console.log(returnData.data);

        });

        console.log("SessionID:"+getSessionID());

        return returnData;

    }    

    var functions = {
        login: login
    }

    return functions;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js: REST client returns the value before it's returned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535689/node-js-rest-client-returns-the-value-before-its-returned)

Answer (score -1):

`.post` is Async, you should do it like this,

```
var login = function(username, password, callback){
..................

client.post(ZABBIX_API, args, function(resData,rawRes){

        if(rawRes.statusCode == 200){
            returnData.status = rawRes.statusCode;
            returnData.data = resData;
        }
        else{
            returnData.status = rawRes.statusCode;
            returnData.data = "Request Failed!";
        }

        reqID = reqID + 1;
        return {login: returnData};
    });
//remove all below return statements
```

Comment: You're still trying to return from an asynchronous function. Use a callback.

Comment: @BenFortune Where did i go wrong? IMO `If...else are Sync` in this context. :/

Comment: The callback ends with a return statement ( `return {login: returnData};` ) but the returned data is not accessible anywhere outside of the callback.

Comment: @RaphaelSerota i forgot to remove that line, anyways the data is successfully returned, so the purpose of the function is fulfilled i guess!